# Horrid stuttering with a Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am using Ubuntu and VirtualBox and making a virtual machine with windows 10. When watching a video the audio was horrid. It sounded like it was stuttering and slowed down. So i checked with playing a video on another device the other device started to to pull ahead. So I have no clue what's causing this, but it seems as though my processor is somehow stuttering. I have no clue what's happening since I'm really new to this whole virtual machine stuff so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please include the details of your system (RAM, CPU, SSD/HDD, etc), config of the Windows 10 VM (CPUs, RAM assigned, etc), and version of VirtualBox.  Please update the question with this info.

Comment: This is normal: You are using a simulated GPU in the VM, whose performance will always be abominable.